# package.init is not getting installed

Tags: debian, packaging, deb, dpkg, debhelper

I have a `project.init` file in the debian directory (along with `rules`, `control`, etc), and I have `dh_installinit` in my `rules` file (in the `binary-arch` rule).

When `dpkg-buildpackage` completes, the init script has been copied to `debian/project/etc/init.d/project`, and the various pre/post scripts have been created.

However, when I actually install the .deb (with `dpkg -i`), the init.d script does not get installed, so I must be missing part of this process.  The "[New Maintainer's Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/)" is pretty sparse on init.d details (it basically says not to use them, because they are too advanced).

The verbose output of the dh_installinit command is:

```
dh_installinit
    install -p -m755 debian/project.init debian/project/etc/init.d/project
    echo "# Automatically added by dh_installinit">> debian/project.postinst.debhelper
    sed "s/#SCRIPT#/project/;s/#INITPARMS#/defaults/;s/#ERROR_HANDLER#/exit \$?/" /usr/share/debhelper/autoscripts/postinst-init >> debian/project.postinst.debhelper
    echo '# End automatically added section' >> debian/project.postinst.debhelper
    echo "# Automatically added by dh_installinit">> debian/project.prerm.debhelper
    sed "s/#SCRIPT#/project/;s/#INITPARMS#/defaults/;s/#ERROR_HANDLER#/exit \$?/" /usr/share/debhelper/autoscripts/prerm-init >> debian/project.prerm.debhelper
    echo '# End automatically added section' >> debian/project.prerm.debhelper
    echo "# Automatically added by dh_installinit">> debian/project.postrm.debhelper
    sed "s/#SCRIPT#/project/;s/#INITPARMS#/defaults/;s/#ERROR_HANDLER#/exit \$?/" /usr/share/debhelper/autoscripts/postrm-init >> debian/project.postrm.debhelper
    echo '# End automatically added section' >> debian/project.postrm.debhelper
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not get installed"? It doesn't exist in the deb, it's not installed into /etc/init.d or no start/stop links are created?

Comment: I'm not sure how to test whether it is in the .deb or not.  It doesn't appear in /etc/init.d (and so obviously the start/stop links aren't created).

Comment: I was having a very similar problem, where a upstart script was being included in the package (you could even see it when listed with dpkg -c), but it wouldn't install.  I eventually tried to changing the compat version (it using 7 and I switched it to 8) and then it installed just fine.

Answer (score 8):

Does your package have an entry for your init script under the `Conffiles` block in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, e.g.

```
Package: <project>
...
Conffiles:
 /etc/init.d/<project> d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

and does `/var/lib/dpkg/info/<project>.conffiles` contain `/etc/init.d/<project>`?

Here's what's happening...

init scripts are marked as configuration files by default, since they live under `/etc`.<sup>1</sup>

I'm guessing you installed the package, removed the init file, then reinstalled the package.

In this case, removing the init file counts as modifying it<sup>2</sup>, and `dpkg` refuses to "overwrite" the "configuration file".

You should be able to fix the problem by removing the `Conffiles` section from `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

Notes:

1. [conffiles - Debian New Maintainer's Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#conffiles)
2. An empty file has MD5sum `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`, but any non-matching checksum will cause the same behavior

Comment: Instead of remove the conffiles entries (and change an expected behavior), maybe it's better ask the `apt` to force the install of the conffiles: `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall <package>`

Comment: I installed a custom package using dpkg-scanpackges and apt-get update/install (with --force-confnew flag). Then I uninstalled it using apt-get remove. Then I deleted my config/log files left over after. Then I re-installed the package in the same way, but the config files were not installed at all.

Removing the Conffiles section fixed my problem too, thanks!

Comment: I also used "--force-confmiss" additionally in order to resolve a similar but separate issue with my init script not being installed after deleting it, as suggested by @RaelGugelminCunha

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be looking at the utility script "update-rc.d" which takes care of creating / removing symlinks in /etc/init.d/ .

Use this script in the DEBIAN control files "postinst" & "postrm".

E.g. for 'postinst':
  update-rc.d mswitch start 20 2 3 4 5 . stop 0 1 6 .

E.g. for 'postrm':
  update-rc.d mswitch remove

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but they probably downvoted this because it's not the right answer, and it's not generally good packaging advice. The `dh_installinit` tool will take care of inserting the right `update-rc.d` calls in postinst and postrm, including making sure the maintainer scripts are being called during the appropriate state transitions.

Comment: Thanks for the note, "the paul".  Note that this procedure worked for me but I take good note there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

At this point I would check the content of the .deb file that is created.  You can use dpkg-deb -c for that purpose.

If the init script is in the .deb, it should get installed in /etc/init.d, just like this:

```
...
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2009-06-03 14:01 ./etc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2009-06-03 14:01 ./etc/init.d/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      2558 2009-02-13 11:27 ./etc/init.d/balance
...
```

If your run a recent version of Debian, the content of your package may be generate from debian/tmp instead of debian/project as you seem to expect.  You can move the files from debian/projet to debian/tmp using dh_install.

Comment: Good theory, but in my case `dpkg-deb -c` shows the file is present in the `.deb`.

Comment: so does the init-script show-up when you extract the package? something like `mkdir /tmp/foo; dpkg -x packge.deb /tmp/foo; ls -l /tmp/foo/etc/init.d`

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, are you using a -P option to other dh_* scripts but not this one? If you use that option, you need to use it on all the dh_* scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I had success, when i only put the project.init file into debian-folder and *do not* add any special constraints to the rules-file. After this step is working, test to add you're special constraints.

To control the success in debian-folder `cat *.postinst.debhelper` contains:

```
# Automatically added by dh_installinit
if [ -x "/etc/init.d/<packagename>" ]; then
    if [ ! -e "/etc/init/<packagename>.conf" ]; then
        update-rc.d <packagename> defaults >/dev/null
    fi
    invoke-rc.d <packagename> start || exit $?
fi
```